# WPS Spreadsheet FILTER function only show 1 result row

Tags: spreadsheet, wps, filterfunction

I try to use FILTER function, but only show 1 result row / cannot show all results
Is there any configuration in WPS spreadsheet to show all result?
Please help ^_^
Thanks

[image]

```
=FILTER(A1:A3,B1:B3=1,ZZ)
```